# Doctrine SQL Query Order By ASC NULL Last

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I use **Doctrine 2.4**. And I try to order my list of campaign by priority ascending with priority NULL and priority to 0 at the end.

```
SELECT * FROM campaign ORDER BY priority IS NULL, priority = 0, priority ASC
```

Have you got an idea how I can do this?

```
$query->addOrderBy('c.priority', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I did that:

```
$query->addSelect('CASE WHEN c.priority IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HIDDEN priority_is_null');
$query->addSelect('CASE WHEN c.priority = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HIDDEN priority_is_zero');
$query->addOrderBy('priority_is_null', 'ASC');
$query->addOrderBy('priority_is_zero', 'ASC');
$query->addOrderBy('c.priority', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
order by case when priority is null then 1 else 0 end, priority
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach without using `addSelect`:

```php
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy("CASE WHEN c.priority IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", 'ASC') // should always be ASC
             ->addOrderBy("CASE WHEN c.priority = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", 'ASC') // should always be ASC
             ->addOrderBy("c.priority", $direction);
```